# Maximizing a #P-hard function

Tags: complexity-classes

Suppose I have a #P-hard function $f(S,x)$ where $x\in T$. Is the problem of $\arg\max_x f(S,x)$ guaranteed to be intractable?

If so, I want to see some references on this topic. If not, is there a general approach to prove such intractability for some typical problems?

For example, we know that S-Set Connectedness is #P-complete [1](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0208032). Is finding the node with maximum connectedness with a particular set also intractable?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a clarification, what are $S$, $T$ ? In the case, for example, of the #P-complete function that counts the number of satisfying assignments of a 3SAT formula ( $\# SAT(x)$ ).

Comment: @MarzioDeBiasi I think in this case, $S$ is useless, $T$ is a set of 3-CNF formulae, and the problem is finding the formula in $T$ that has maximum number of satisfying assignments.

Comment: ok! You can prove that the problem is intractable ($\#P$-complete) using the following approach: given a SAT formula $\varphi$ you can calculate $\#SAT(\varphi)$, using a sequence of $T_i = \{\varphi, F_n \}$ where $F_n$ is a custom-built formula having exactly $n$ satisfying assignments. If $argmax$ returns $F_n$ then you pick $T_{i+1} = \{ \varphi, F_{n/2} \}$ where $F_{n/2}$ has exactly $n/2$ satisfying assignments, otherwise you pick $T_{i+1} = \{ \varphi, F_{2n}\}$; and so on. Informally, you make a sort of binary search using $argmax$.